# Extending gem with another

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a executable gem and I want to extend it's functionality with other gems which extends it code. The problem is that I can't bypass Gemfile gem definition to work. I have made an example in bitbucket.com

The main gem is Foo:
https://bitbucket.org/aurimasniekis/foo

Extensions to foo is Foo-bar
https://bitbucket.org/aurimasniekis/foo-bar

to test it run `foo bar` in terminal it will throw the error `(Cannot load such file -- foo-bar) (RuntimeError)` but if I add `gem "foo-bar"` to Foo gemfile it will work. My questions is how to bypass Gemfile definition of gems needed.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a bundler from main gem fixed all the problems with missing gem... Why don't let use gems which are not defined in gemfile